# How to fix "Property 'click' does not exist on type 'never'" on Next Link element?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have a form that wraps an input, and a submit button. When the input change event is triggered, the link href is updated. The submit logic of the form simply clicks the link.

The logic works, and the link clicks and redirects, however, `searchLinkRef.current.click()` causes the error below in VS Code:

> "Property 'click' does not exist on type 'never'"

Please, how can it be fixed?

```
//imports 
import Link from "next/link";
import {  useRef, useState } from "react";


const Test = () =>{
const [searchLink, setSearchLink] = useState(<></>);
const searchLinkRef = useRef(null);

  const setter = (
    link: any = <></>
  ) => {
    setSearchLink(link);
  };

const inputChangeHandler = (event: any) => {
    const searchString = event.target.value.toLowerCase().trim();
  setter(
    <Link href={`./search/${searchString}`} ref={searchLinkRef} />
  );

const searchSubmitHandler = (event: any) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (searchLinkRef.current !== null) {
      searchLinkRef.current.click();
    }
  };

  return({searchLink})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because you didn't give the right type to `searchLinkRef` as you have called `useRef`. This will fix your issue:

```typescript
const searchLinkRef = useRef<HTMLAnchorElement>(null);
```

Comment: I have tried this before but the code gave me more errors.
I copied and pasted this now and it worked. 
I realize my error was using <HTMLAnchorElement/>, instead of <HTMLAnchorElement>.
Thank you.